# Cancel all Kotlin coroutines pending jobs on ViewModel's onCleared()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension, kotlin-coroutines

Stopping **jobs** in onCleared() of **ViewModel** after activity finish shows the **JobCancellationException: Job is being canceled** and keeps app freeze crash:

What would be the right way to cancel all kotlin coroutines pending jobs from ViewModel's onCleared() in Android

My code inside viewModel:

```
private val job = SupervisorJob()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

 uiScope.launch {
        try {
            repeat(152212000001) { it ->
                try {
                    Log.d("Timer : ", it)
                    delay(1000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Inside ViewModel:

```
override fun onCleared() {
    job.cancel()
    super.onCleared()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Easy Coroutines in Android: viewModelScope blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471):

> `viewModelScope` contributes to [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#structured-concurrency) by adding an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) to the ViewModel class that automatically cancels its child coroutines when the ViewModel is destroyed.

So by adding a dependency on `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-alpha02` (or higher), you'll be able to just use `viewModelScope` to do the right thing by default:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    repeat(152212000001) { it ->
        Log.d("Timer : ", it)
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I was able to cancel the coroutine job but not able to cancel long process child jobs.
So, does it immediately cancel the child coroutines after view model destroyed?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of structured concurrency. As long as you don't mess up by launching coroutines in another scope like `GlobalScope`, they will register as children of `viewModelScope` and get cancelled recursively.

Comment: Is it good practice to use delay in viewModel to give some pause? If not, what we can use?